# img tags in javascript for autocomplete search

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I am designing an autocomplete search which will have text and images in the results (working fine). However my images are blurred due to the standard image cache. So I was wondering if it is possible to resize images in the javascript to make them look neat and small?

Below is my javascript where I am using the img tags.

Could anyone please assist me with this? Thanks.

```
.data('autocomplete')._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
   return $('<li>')
   .data('item.autocomplete', item)
   .append("<a>"+"<img src ='/account/"+item.id+"/icon/preview'/>" + item.label+"</a>")
   .appendTo(ul);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a CSS properties for your image tag or change it through script like

```
image.style.width='50%';
image.style.height='auto';
```

by doing this you can maintain the resolution of image. so it can not lose its quality.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this code will help you, here i used jquery UI with inline style

```
$.ui.autocomplete.prototype._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
return $("<li></li>")
.data("item.autocomplete", item)
.append("<a><img src='/account/"+item.id + "/icon/preview' style='position:relative; top:30px;width:50px;height:50px;' />"+item.label+ "</a>").appendTo( ul );
};}
```